# ObservableObject with ObservableObject property is not triggering SwiftUI Update

Tags: swiftui, observableobject, swiftui-environment

```
// NavigationState.swift
class NavigationState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contentViewNavigation = ContentViewNavigationState()
    //@Published var selectedTab = 0
}

// App.swift
@main
struct SwiftUIDeepLinkApp: App {
    @StateObject private var navigationAppState = NavigationState()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(navigationAppState)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                        print("Dispatch called")
                        navigationAppState.contentViewNavigation.selectedTab = 1
                        //navigationAppState.selectedTab = 1
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}

// ContentView.swift
class ContentViewNavigationState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationState: NavigationState

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $navigationState.contentViewNavigation.selectedTab) {
            HomeContainerFlow1()
                .tabItem { Text("Flow 1") }
                .tag(0)
        
            HomeContainerFlow2()
                .embededInNavigation()
                .tabItem { Text("Flow 2") }
                .tag(1)
        }.onReceive(navigationState.contentViewNavigation.$selectedTab, perform: { output in
            print("Value changed: \(output)")
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm defining a global state ("NavigationState") to handle the Navigation of the app (i.e Tab Selection). So, I have an ObservableObject (NavigationState) that will have properties for each screen navigation state (i.e ContentViewNavigationState - another ObservableObject).

**Actual Behavior**

In this example, I'm modifying the state in App.swift file inside a DispatchQueue.asyncAfter, the state is changing (because ContentView's onReceive modifier is displaying the update value) but is not triggering any update in ContentView.

**Expected Behavior**

The selected tab should be changed based on state.

- The interesting part is that if I also modify another property (i.e the commented `selectedTab`), in that case the update is triggered, but not when only update a contentViewNavigation's property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view must observe ObservableObject explicitly if want to be updated if the object has changed.

In your case you observe parent of observable but not inner observable. The `contentViewNavigation` in your scenario is not changed by itself, because it is just reference to inner object.

So the solution might be as in demo below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationState: NavigationState

    var body: some View {
       // separate view which observe inner ObservableObject
       MainView(contentNavigation: navigationState.contentViewNavigation)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentNavigation: ContentViewNavigationState

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $contentNavigation.selectedTab) {
            HomeContainerFlow1()
                .tabItem { Text("Flow 1") }
                .tag(0)
        
            HomeContainerFlow2()
                .embededInNavigation()
                .tabItem { Text("Flow 2") }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But then it means that for each separated view, I will have to wrapped like in a ContentView to be able to receive the state and just pass the info required?